# SSL/TLS Socket Connection in Swift 2 with certificate

Tags: swift, sockets, ssl, connection, certificate

What is the best freeware framework/lib to use SSL/TLS Socket Connection in Swift 2 with certificate if exist? If not exist please write me simply example how i can use this protocol in swift. Thanks for fast answers.

Comment: I don't know What I can do socket with tls 1.2  in swift 2

Comment: you may be insterested in [link](https://github.com/socketio)